# Match RegEx with Caret Negation (exclude)

Tags: javascript, regex, negate

I want to filter my array with an exclusion so I did

```
const exclude = include.filter((d) => {
                let negate1 = '[^'
                let negate2 = ']'
                let negate = negate1.concat(letterexc).concat(negate2)
                let exclRegex = new RegExp(negate,'g')
                console.log(exclRegex) //return --> /[^anyletter]/g
                return d.list.match(exclRegex)
            })
```

I add `[^` and `letterexc` variable from an input field and `]` to make a negation regex, but its not working. not filtering anything.

I read and tried my pattern here https://regexr.com/ and found if my pattern actually works, but not on my own.

Another article from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [link](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/finiteautomata/Section07/sect07_12.html) says the similar pattern works (with caret after bracket)

[image: screenshot]

EDIT:
I added a pen [link](https://codepen.io/louislugas/pen/ZEaBxao?editors=0011). It's filtering with 2 input field for letter included and excluded. The included filter works fine

Comment: What are the values of `include` and `letterexc` and what is the type of `list` ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I edited and added a working pen. the `include` is the previous array filter i've done. `letterexc` is a variable from the input field value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it

I change

```
d.list.match(exclRegex)
```

to

```
!d.list.match(exclRegex)
```

while removing the carat `^` from the concat

complete code excerpt :

```
const exclude = include.filter((d) => {
                let negate1 = '['
                let negate2 = ']'
                let negate = negate1.concat(letterexc).concat(negate2)
                let exclRegex = new RegExp(negate,'g')
                console.log(exclRegex) //return --> /[^anyletter]/g
                return !d.list.match(exclRegex)
            })
```